# Elements of order 5 in $A_6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, symmetric-groups, alternative-proof

I am trying to find the elements of order 5 in $A_6$ and I understand that they are of the form $(abcde)$, correct? So the number of elements is $(6*5*4*3*2)/5$=144. I looked somewhere else and it said it was $6!/5$, which is the same thing because the only thing that is left off is multiplying by 1. But why would I have to do $6!$ ?

Comment: Well, co construct a 5-cycle (abcde) you have 6 possibilities for $a$, 5 for $b$, ... , $2$ for $e$ but then you need to devide by $5$ because each 5-cycle is represented by 5 different conventions ($abcde=bcdea=\ldots =eabcd$).

Comment: I understand that but why use factorial?

Comment: Once you choose $a$ (6 options), you have 5 options for $b$; once you chose $ab$ you have 4 options for $c$ etc.

Comment: right so 3 options for d and 2 options for e. whats the point of including the 1 from the factorial?

Comment: It doesn't matter, multiplying by 1 does nothing. Just shorter notation.

Comment: (Once you have chosen $abcde$, you can assign to it the permutation $(1,2,3,4,5,6)\mapsto (abcdef)$ where $f$ is the remaining one and this is bijection on $6$-permutations)

Answer (score 1):

The sign of a permutation is odd if and only if it has an odd number of even cycles in its decomposition. How many even cycles does a $5-$cycle have?

Since the order of a permutation is the least common multiple of the lengths of its cycles the permutations of order $5$ are exactly the $5$ cycles. to count them you can first select the elements in the cycle in $6$ ways ( this is the same as selecting the element not in the cycle.

Once these have been selected thee are $5!$ ways to order them inside the brackets. However out of these ways to write them there are groups of $5$ that represent the same permutation but are just rotated. So we get $4!$ cycles once the elements in the cycle have been selected.

Thus there are $4!6=\frac{6!}{5}$ elements of order $5$ in $A_6$ (and also in $S_6$)

Comment: zero right? Honestly I dont really know much about this. do you know of any online source where I could read more about it?

Comment: The book abstract algebra by Dummit and Foote has a chapter on permutations and the alternating group which is pretty good, it also has excercises, also rotman's book on group theory starts off with permutations.